# can't open qt project file in visual studio 2008

Tags: c++, visual-studio, qt

I have installed Qt sdk 4,7  , qt libs for Visual studio , and the addin for VS. 
And I want to open a qt project ( psi - im ) that was created with QT compiler (qt creator) and is a " .pro" file. 
because I've installed the qt addin for VS , I have menu ->QT-> open  ".pro" file. But when I try it just loads for some time and then disappears, and nothing is opened.

have you ever encountered this?? 
Any suggestions?

VS ver = 2008

Comment: I struggled with Qt/VS relations for almost a month. Then I just switched to QtCreator. Less painful

Comment: I tied using QtCreator but i failed to compile the project so i hopped this adding could convert it to a visual studio project

Answer (score 1):

to convert a qt project to visual studio project, execute this command in your console:

`qmake -tp vc -r xxxxxx.pro`